# Windows 10, can the view of Pictures folders show extra large icons, while all others show details?

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop.ini

I have a very high resolution monitor, and the default icon views are far too small for images. So I want all picture views to show extra large icons. But I'm a developer, and I need to see all the file details for the contents of other folders.
So I want to have all Picture folders "Permanently" show extra large icons, while all others  "Permanently" show details. How can I do this?
I thought this the purpose of "desktop.ini" files, but I don't know how to edit them to get what I want.